# How to use MaxentTagger with Maven

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I cannot find a single understandable tutorial on how to use the Standford NLP MaxentPos Tagger:

I have added the following to my POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <classifier>models-english</classifier>
</dependency>
```

and am trying to instantiate it with:

```
 MaxentTagger maxentTagger = new MaxentTagger("english-left3words-distsim.tagger")
```

I have also tried using "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as path.

I put the .tagger file into the resources folder. Where does it have to be?

> Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException:
>   Error while loading a tagger model (probably missing model file)

and

> incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = 2

Comment: You said OpenNLP but you are using Stanford NLP dependencies. Which is it?

Comment: Thank you, my bad. I meant Stanford NLP